# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console>: Object's name 'scrollList' is not unique

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, maya

New to python and coding in general so I'm having trouble understanding how to do stuff. This is for a class so I can't do mel or pyMel.
I'm trying to write a code that can save faces and store them in a UI however it gives me an error that "# Error: RuntimeError: file  line 28: Object's name 'scrollList' is not unique."
Can't seem to figure out how to solve this unique name issue.

here is my code if it helps

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def button_closure(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    Function to
    wrap buttons
    '''
    def wrapped(_):
        fn(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapped

def refresh_lst(*args):
    '''
    function to
    refresh list
    '''
    selection = cmds.ls(sl = True)
    # Removes the current selection from the textScrollList
    cmds.textScrollList("scrollList", e = True, removeAll = True)
    # Adds in the newest selection to be reflected in the textScrollList
    cmds.textScrollList("scrollList", query=True,append = selection, e = True)

def store_selected(scrollList):
    '''
    Function to
    select faces and store
    in a textScrollList
    '''
    face_list=[]
    selection = cmds.ls(sl=True) #takes selection
    face_list = cmds.filterExpand(selection,sm=34) #makes sure to only select just the poly face
    cmds.textScrollList("scrollList",enable=True, append=face_list[0]) #adds the selection to the list
    print(face_list)
    
def select_stored(scrollList):
    txt =cmds.textScrollList("scrollList",query=True, si=True) #to store it
    cmds.select(txt, r=True)
    cmds.filterExpand(selection,sm=34)
    print(txt, 'is selected')

def parent_window():
    
    window = cmds.window( title="UV ToolBar", iconName='UVTools', widthHeight=(316, 500))
    
    # scroll bar
    cmds.scrollLayout( childResizable = True, borderVisible= True, verticalScrollBarAlwaysVisible=True)
    
    master_layout= main = cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn = True, rowSpacing = 5)
    # Text Scroll List 
    selection_textscrollList = cmds.textScrollList("scrollList", ams = True)
    cmds.button(label='Store', command= button_closure(store_selected, selection_textscrollList))

    cmds.setParent(master_layout)
    cmds.button(label='Select Stored', command= button_closure(select_stored, selection_textscrollList))
    cmds.button(label='Refresh List', command= button_closure(refresh_lst, selection_textscrollList))
    
    # Set its parent to the Maya window (denoted by '..')
    cmds.setParent( '..' )
    
    # Separator for parent window
    cmds.separator(height=5, style='out', backgroundColor= [0.2, 0.2, 0.3])
     
    # Show the window that we created (window)
    cmds.showWindow( window )

    return selection_textscrollList
    
parent_window()
```

Tried multiple ways like defining a function or using different *args

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

First make sure there is no window with the same name by using `deleteUI` if it exists. Next, it is not a good practice to rely on names for maya ui elements because maya renames the elements if it thinks this is necessary. So something like:

```
selection_textscrollList = cmds.textScrollList("scrollList", ams = True)
```

may return an element called `window1|scrollLayout13|columnLayout56|scrollList` or it returns an element called `window1|scrollLayout13|columnLayout57|scrollList1` so the best way is to always use the returned names to access UI elements. To make this access easier I recommend the usage of a class. This way you can store all needed UI names and callbacks internally in the class and access easily them if needed without the need of global variables or strange callback constructs.